# Comparar tabelas e adicionar resultado a linha

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Tenhos duas tabelas

Tabela 1

> N3_FILIAL | N3_CBASE | N3_ITEM | N3_CCDEPR

```
0N3_FILIAL  | N3_CBASE  | N3_ITEM   | N3_CCONTAB    | N3_CUSTBEM    | N3_VORIG1     | N3_TXDEPR1    | N3_VRDACM1
0001          BENF000001  0001        12301020014     12001002        491.810,00      10,0000         462.301,40
```

Tabela 2

> N4_FILIAL | N4_CBASE | N4_ITEM | N4_CONTA

```
N4_FILIAL   | N4_CBASE  | N4_ITEM   | N4_CONTA
0001          BENF000001  0001        12301020014
0001          BENF000001  0001        12301020014
0001          BENF000001  0001        12301020014
0001          BENF000001  0001        12301020014
0001          BENF000001  0001        12301020014
```

Os valores são os mesmos, porém, na tabela 1 tenho apenas uma linha e na 2 mais de 1.

Gostaria de saber como posso montar uma query para procurar na tabela 2 essa condição (`0001 | BENF000001 | 0001 | 12301020014`) e a frente de cada registro encontrado na tabela 2 eu adicionar o restante da linha da tabela 1. (`N3_CUSTBEM | N3_VORIG1 | N3_TXDEPR1 | N3_VRDACM1`)

Muito obrigado!

Comment: Olá @Gustavo. Qual o objetivo? Se pretende tratar os valores da `Tabela 1` e consegue ligar as duas tabelas por esses campos que descreveu, não precisa de ter essa informação na `Tabela 2`!

Comment: Não sei se entendi corretamente sua pergunta mas me parece que com a cláusula GROUP BY acrescida de uma função de agregação apropriada, tipo a string_agg do PostgreSQL, possa atende-lo.

Comment: @Gustavo Freire , mostre como precisa que os dados sejam exibidos.

Comment: @Motta Preciso que ao achar o critério (0001 | BENF000001 | 0001 | 12301020014) na tabela 2
ele escreva da segui forma na TABELA 2:
0001 | BENF000001 | 0001 | 12301020014 + VALORES DE N3_CUSTBEM | N3_VORIG1 | N3_TXDEPR1 | N3_VRDACM1) da tabela 1

Comment: Não entendi por que o join não resolve , mostre na pergunte como precisa da exibição , confesso não ter entendido.

Answer (score 0):

Penso que a consulta abaixo devolve o que pretende:

```
SELECT      DISTINCT 
            T2.*
        ,   T1.N3_CUSTBEM
        ,   T1.N3_VORIG1
        ,   T1.N3_TXDEPR1
        ,   T1.N3_VRDACM1
FROM        T2
INNER JOIN  T1  ON  T1.N3_FILIAL    = T2.N4_FILIAL
                AND T1.N3_CBASE     = T2.N4_CBASE
                AND T1.N3_ITEM      = T2.N4_ITEM
                AND T1.N3_CCONTAB   = T2.N4_CONTA
```

Pode validar o cenário no [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8cAWSp755CVxSSoT9umFjm/0) (está construído para **MySQL**, mas a sintaxe funciona para qualquer SGBD).